# estoy intentando extraer una imagen desde una ruta guardada en la base de datos :( y me sale este error

Tags: php

estoy intentando extraer una imagen desde una ruta guardada en la base de datos :( 
 y me sale este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query():
Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, string given in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mostrar img\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mostrar img\index.php(10): 
mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM p...', Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mostrar img\index.php on line 10
```

conexion.php es aparte...

index

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" ; charset="iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include("conexion.php");
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $base);
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM productos", $conexion) or die("Error en: busqueda" . mysql_error());
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        do {
            $ruta = $row['url_imagen']
    ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $ruta; ?>" width="190" height="160"><br>
    <?php
            echo "<table border = '1' bordercolor='000000'>";
            echo "" . $row["producto"] . "<br>";
            echo "</table>";
        } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    } else {
        echo "No Se Ha Encontrado Ningun Registro";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Conexion.php (en un archivo aparte)

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123');
    $base = "img";
?>
```

Comment: Y para empezar, `mysqli_query ()` primero lleva la conexion, luego la consulta... lo estas haciendo al reves

Comment: Es como dice @Excorpion. Además, aprovecha para modernizar tu código, usando el estilo orientado a objetos, es más claro, más breve y evita errores de este tipo. También, la nueva API admite el nombre de la base de datos como un cuarto parámetro al conectar, por lo que puedes prescindir de `mysqli_select_db`. Y, más cosas, ¿por qué usas dos  `mysql_fetch_array` y  `do ... while` para leer los resultados y no `while` simplemente? Lo dicho, moderniza tu código y cuidado con los tutoriales con que estás aprendiendo si es el caso.